# Error while configuring REST for Oracle APEX on Windows

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-apex, oracle-18c

I'm trying to deploy `Oracle APEX 18` on Windows 8.1 PC using `Oracle REST Data Services` and `Oracle Database 18c XE` following [this guide](https://www.lkakarla.com/2018/12/apex-182-setup-on-windows-with-ords.html).

But when I'm trying to run `@apex_rest_config.sql` I get this error - `Enter: GetConsoleMode failed, LastError=|6| at Drive_letter:/DB_install_folder/dbhomeXE/perl/site/lib/Term/ReadKey.pm line 334.`

In CMD it looks like this:
[image: error as seen in CMD]

Every `apex_rest_config#.log` file looks similar to this:
[image: log file]

What could be causing this problem? Why `@apex_rest_config.sql` doesn't ask new passwords for `APEX_LISTENER` and `APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER`, as it does in the guide?
Does it have something to do with this `ORA-03113: end of file on communication channel` error? Is there any fix or workaround?

**Update 1:** trying to implement [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4204556) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works if you:

1. create a new database (or use existing)
2. do `alter session set container = yourDBname`
3. and only then run `@apexins.sql` and other installation and config scripts (e.g., `@apxchpwd.sql`, `@apex_rest_config.sql`).

This will lead to creation of a new APEX instance inside current DB.

Answer (score -2):

Perform only the following commands:

```
19c\apex>sqlplus sys/PW@DBname as sysdba

alter session set container = yourDBname;

@apex_rest_config.sql
```

Comment: This is marginally different from an existing answer.  Please edit and explain why this is better.